# How to solve following problem using binary search?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

We are given an array of integers and we need to find **size** of smallest subsegment such that after removing it all element in array are distinct .How to solve this problem using binary search in O(nlogn) ? I tried to read various submission's which use binary search but i couldn't understand them .

My attempt - I solve this problem in n^2logn using brute force but i want to know how to apply binary search to solve this problem in O(nlogn).

Link of Problem  - https://codeforces.com/contest/1208/problem/B

Link of one of the solution implementing binary search  -https://codeforces.com/contest/1208/submission/59494540

Comment: Do not post links, post problem description and your attempt or code you are trying here.

Comment: @SomeDude  I have provided description and by providing link people can see test cases etc to have better understanding of problem .

Comment: @MooingDuck No.In that case won't that be whole array itself ?

Comment: @Faser you could still post your test cases here.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by how, you have a solution right in the question

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I did not understood how to implement it using binary search  . the link of solution i posted is not mine , it is of some one else using binary search .

Comment: @Faser - it appears you're confused with regards to what binary search is, and in any case your expected big-O is not that of binary search

Comment: I think one can use a divide-and-conquer strategy that's O(nLogn) to solve this, but am uncertain how to use a binary _search_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked solution, the function `check(int siz)` returns true if it's possible to make all number unique by removing a subarray of size `siz`.  It does this in *O(n)* time.

Since `check(x) == true` implies that `check(y) == true` for all `y >= x`, the `main()` function can do a binary search to find the smallest value of `siz` for which `check(siz) == true`, which is the solution to the problem.

If `check(mid) == true`, then the answer is not bigger than `mid`.  If `check(mid) == false`, then the answer is bigger than `mid`.

The binary search requires *O(log n)* evaluations of `check` for a total of *O(n log n)* time.